# Dynamic SVG path

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

Supposed that I have the following SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="237" height="129" viewBox="0 0 237 129" fill="none">
  <path d="M228 1H9C4.58172 1 1 4.58172 1 9V91V104V127L20 111.483L228 112C232.418 112 236 108.418 236 104V9C236 4.58172 232.418 1 228 1Z" fill="#F6F6F6" />
  <path d="M1 104V9C1 4.58172 4.58172 1 9 1H228C232.418 1 236 4.58172 236 9V104C236 108.418 232.418 112 228 112L20 111.483L1 127V91" stroke="#E8E8E8" />
  <foreignObject x="15" y="0" width="200" height="130">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fringilla quam eu faci lisis mollis. </p>
  </foreignObject>
 </svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="235" height="86" viewBox="0 0 235 86" fill="none">
  <path d="M8 0H227C231.418 0 235 3.58172 235 8V50V63V86L216 70.4828L8 71C3.58173 71 0 67.4183 0 63V8C0 3.58172 3.58173 0 8 0Z" fill="#5DB075"/>
  <foreignObject x="15" y="0" width="200" height="80">
    <p style="color: white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

I was thinking to make the height dynamic based on text length.

For example the first SVG would be something like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="237" height={50 + (27 * text.length / 27)} viewBox={`0 0 237 ${50 + (27 * text.length / 27)}`} fill="none">
  <path d="M228 1H9C4.58172 1 1 4.58172 1 9V91V104V127L20 111.483L228 112C232.418 112 236 108.418 236 104V9C236 4.58172 232.418 1 228 1Z" fill="#F6F6F6" />
  <path d="M1 104V9C1 4.58172 4.58172 1 9 1H228C232.418 1 236 4.58172 236 9V104C236 108.418 232.418 112 228 112L20 111.483L1 127V91" stroke="#E8E8E8" />
  <foreignObject x="15" y="15" width="150" height={20 + (27 * text.length / 27)}>
    <p>{text}</p>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

And the second SVG would be something like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="235" height={50 + (27 * text.length / 27)} viewBox={`0 0 237 ${50 + (27 * text.length / 27)}`} fill="none">
  <path d="M8 0H227C231.418 0 235 3.58172 235 8V50V63V86L216 70.4828L8 71C3.58173 71 0 67.4183 0 63V8C0 3.58172 3.58173 0 8 0Z" fill="#5DB075" />
  <foreignObject x="15" y="15" width="150" height={20 + (27 * text.length / 27)}>
    <p style="color: white">{text}</p>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Current problem with this approach is, the path D wasn't manipulated to be reflecting the actual height.

For example in snippet if text was short would look something like:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="237" height="50" viewBox="0 0 237 50" fill="none">
  <path d="M228 1H9C4.58172 1 1 4.58172 1 9V91V104V127L20 111.483L228 112C232.418 112 236 108.418 236 104V9C236 4.58172 232.418 1 228 1Z" fill="#F6F6F6" />
  <path d="M1 104V9C1 4.58172 4.58172 1 9 1H228C232.418 1 236 4.58172 236 9V104C236 108.418 232.418 112 228 112L20 111.483L1 127V91" stroke="#E8E8E8" />
  <foreignObject x="15" y="0" width="200" height="130">
    <p>test </p>
  </foreignObject>
 </svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="235" height="50" viewBox="0 0 235 50" fill="none">
  <path d="M8 0H227C231.418 0 235 3.58172 235 8V50V63V86L216 70.4828L8 71C3.58173 71 0 67.4183 0 63V8C0 3.58172 3.58173 0 8 0Z" fill="#5DB075"/>
  <foreignObject x="15" y="0" width="200" height="80">
    <p style="color: white">test </p>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Is there any better way to update the SVG shape dynamically based on text length?

Comment: SVG is a complicated way of doing this. It's entirely possible to manage this with standard HTML/CSS.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76327853/scrollable-gradient-chat-bubbles and adjust the style should be better way than adjusting SVG. (Other reference: https://codepen.io/Founts/pen/AJyVOr)

Answer (score 0):

So, here one solution to mimic the style in html/css. You can adjust the css to match your liking: colors and bubble shapes and so on...

```css
.buble {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  min-width: min-content;
  clear: both;
  hyphens: auto;
}

.recv {
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: 2px solid silver;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  float: left;
}

.recv.handle:after {
  content: "";
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: 2px solid silver;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: skewY(-45deg) translate(0, -0.5rem);
}

.send {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  background: #99dd99;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.send.handle:after {
  content: "";
  background: #99dd99;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 1rem;
  transform: skewY(45deg) translate(0, -0.5rem);
}

p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  min-height: 1rem;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Simple Chat using css</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="buble recv handle">
      <p>Received extra long message with handle and some content that should span to next line automatically if so.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="buble send">
      <p>Sent short message without handle</p>
    </div>

    <div class="buble recv">
      <p>Received message</p>
    </div>

    <div class="buble send handle">
      <p>Multilines <br />works nicely.<br />Long sent message with handle.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="buble recv handle">
      <p>Received message</p>
    </div>

    <div class="buble recv handle">
      <p>Received message</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard HTML/CSS way:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 16px auto;
  padding: 0 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.receive,
.send {
  margin: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.receive {
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
}

.send {
  background-color: #5DB075;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  color: white;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.talktext {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.talktext p {
  -webkit-margin-before: 0em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0em;
}

.receive:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  background: #F6F6F6;
  border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  left: -1px;
  bottom: -18px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: skewY(-45deg) translate(0, -0.5rem);
}

.send:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: auto;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: -20px;
  border: 12px solid;
  border-color: #5DB075 #5DB075 transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="receive talktext">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fringilla quam eu faci lisis mollis.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="send talktext">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="receive talktext">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>

  <div class="send talktext">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```